# mouse movements in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to use a mouse click and drag in wpf? I have disabled the borders on my app within the xaml code but in the code behind im trying to do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Size? _mouseGrabOffset;


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
                _mouseGrabOffset = new Size(e.Location);
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
                _mouseGrabOffset = new Size(e.Location);
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
        }
        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _mouseGrabOffset = null;

            base.OnMouseUp(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_mouseGrabOffset.HasValue)
            {
                this.Location = Cursor.Position - _mouseGrabOffset.Value;
            }

            base.OnMouseMove(e);
        }
```

Basically because my borders and title bar is disabled this code should allow control of the application anywhere where i click.

I just cant get it to work because this is based on windows forms.

**EDIT**

If I try this I get a definition error but im unsure how else to handle it:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Size? _mouseGrabOffset;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MainWindow_OnMouseDown);

    }
    void MainWindow_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            _mouseGrabOffset = new Size(e.Location);
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mouseGrabOffset.HasValue)
        {
            this.Location = Cursor.Position - _mouseGrabOffset.Value;
        }

        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }
```

**RE EDIT**

So I have now tryed a new method as mentioned below but still nothing.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //private Size? _mouseGrabOffset;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MainWindow_OnMouseDown);

    }
    public enum MouseButtonType 
    {
        Left,
        Middle,
        Right,
        XButton1,
        XButton2,

    }
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
    }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with asp.net?

Comment: `MouseEventArgs` should be `MouseButtonEventArgs` for `MainWindow_OnMouseDown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Window's code behind you override OnMouseDown and/or OnPreviewMouseDown

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
}
```

Second, check the MouseButtonEventArgs ChangedButton property to determine which Button was pressed.
    public enum MouseButton (Left, Middle, Right, XButton1, XButton2}
The relevant namespace is System.Windows.Input; System.Windows.Forms is incorrect.

Your Window should not subscribe to its own events as previously suggested. Use the overrides.
    this.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MainWindow_OnMouseDown); // Incorrect

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, you register for events like this in code behind :

```
  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent(); 
      this.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MainWindow_MouseDown);
  }
  void MainWindow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  { 
        //handle it
  }
```

Or register for it in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        ...
        MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
```

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding WPF events are in the [`System.Windows.Input` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604577.aspx). Specifically, the [`MouseDown` attached event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mousedown.aspx), [`MouseUp` attached event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mouseup.aspx), and [`MouseMove` attached event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mousemove.aspx). To find out which button was pressed you use the [`ChangedButton` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.changedbutton.aspx) of the [`MouseButtonEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611349.aspx).